# Casting list of one type with generic to another

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a 3 classes:

```
BaseNotification {}

ManagerNotification extends BaseNotification {}

NotificationWrapper<T extends BaseNotification> {
   private T message
}
```

What a best way to cast `List<NotificationWrapper<ManagerNotification>>` to `List<NotificationWrapper<?>>` (or `List<NotificationWrapper<? extends BaseNotification>>`) ?

I want to avoid unchecked casting warning also.

Comment: A `List<? extends NotificationWrapper<ManagerNotification>>` is usable where a `List<? extends NotificationWrapper<? extends BaseNotification>>` is needed.

Comment: You could either change the type of your original list or use stream().map(...).toList() the second would create a new list and copy the values though. You can't cast a list to a more generic type because this would violate type safety guarantees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example why you can't widen the type of a generic Type based on your example:

```
StaffNotifcation extends BaseNotification {}

List<NotificationWrapper<ManagerNotification>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new NotificationWrapper<>(new ManagerNotification()); // <- contructor taking T implied for NotificationWrapper

list.add(new NotificationWrapper<>(new StaffNotification()); // <- fails because StaffNotfication != ManagerNotification

List<NotificationWrapper<?>> castList = (List<NotificationWrapper<?>>) list; // <- unsafe widening of NotificationWrapper

castList.add(new NotificationWrapper<>(new StaffNotification()); // <- compiles but throws ClassCastException at runtime
```

As you can see casting generic types in any way like this is not safe or desirable. To get this List more flexible you need to use wildcards with the desired bounds ("? extends Foo" or "? super Foo" or a combination of those). I recomend [nipafx generics playlist](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_-IO8LOLuNocgK76GAn9j9-flGAJT5FS) to get a deeper understanding in generics.